# How can (manually) edit the xml format of element tree

Tags: python, elementtree

Let's say I have 2 XML files like this:

*version1.xml:*

```
<object>
    <name>boat</name>
    <pose>Unspecified</pose>
    <truncated>0</truncated>
    <difficult>0</difficult>
    <bndbox>
        <xmin>0</xmin>
        <ymin>434</ymin>
        <xmax>152</xmax>
        <ymax>504</ymax>
    </bndbox>
</object>
```

*version2.xml:*

```
<object><name>boat</name><pose>Unspecified</pose><truncated>0</truncated><difficult>0</difficult><bndbox><xmin>0</xmin><ymin>434</ymin><xmax>152</xmax><ymax>504</ymax></bndbox></object>
```

the only difference between them is the whitespaces which make the first one quite more human readable. I am trying to find how I could transform the second one into the first format.

I know I can use some work around like using this function from this [GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/jefftriplett/3980637) (and I have in other occasions also):

```
from xml.dom import minidom
from xml.etree import ElementTree


def prettify(elem):
    """
    Return a pretty-printed XML string for the Element.
    """
    rough_string = ElementTree.tostring(elem, 'utf-8')
    reparsed = minidom.parseString(rough_string)
    return reparsed.toprettyxml(indent='  ')
```

but I am not looking for this (my needs involve a partially formatted XML which does not work flawlessly with the above function).

If I check each element's text difference I get just this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_path1 = 'path/to/version1.xml'
xml_path2 = 'path/to/version2.xml'
tree1 = ET.parse(xml_path1)
annot1 = tree1.getroot()
tree2 = ET.parse(xml_path2)
annot2 = tree2.getroot()

for elem1, elem2 in zip(annot1.iter(), annot2.iter()):
    if repr(elem1.text) != repr(elem2.text):
        print(elem1, repr(elem1.text), elem2, repr(elem2.text))
```

with output:

```
<Element 'object' at 0x7fb26fc2d9f8> '\n\t' <Element 'object' at 0x7fb1c4e4da48> None
<Element 'bndbox' at 0x7fb1c4e4d8b8> '\n\t\t' <Element 'bndbox' at 0x7fb1c4e4dbd8> None
```

If I change the specified text to the corresponding version1 texts, of course, it does change the format to the affected elements but that it.

```
ET.dump(annot2)
```

Output:

```
<object>
    <name>boat</name><pose>Unspecified</pose><truncated>0</truncated><difficult>0</difficult><bndbox>
        <xmin>0</xmin><ymin>434</ymin><xmax>152</xmax><ymax>504</ymax></bndbox></object>
```

with the desired output being of course:

```
ET.dump(annot1)
```

Output:

```
<object>
    <name>boat</name>
    <pose>Unspecified</pose>
    <truncated>0</truncated>
    <difficult>0</difficult>
    <bndbox>
        <xmin>0</xmin>
        <ymin>434</ymin>
        <xmax>152</xmax>
        <ymax>504</ymax>
    </bndbox>
</object>
```

So, what's the deal with the formatting? I know that it does not actually affect the contents of XML (machines consider the content to be the same I think) but where Element Tree saves this information eludes me.

- Is there any (hard and probably not efficient) way to control the
  format of the XML?
- And how come some elements which contain the actual values like `xmin` in my case only display this value and hide the formatting text while others like `bndbox` which actually encapsulates other sub-elements do display these formatting strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing whitespace is in `Element.tail` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.tail)).

When generating the output, ElementTree prints the start element, the contents, the end element and then the tail.

Here is a trick to format a subtree (and leave the rest of the document alone):

1. Pretty print the subtree using your trick above
2. Convert to string
3. Replace `"\n"` in the string with `"\n" + ("    "*level)` where `level` is the depth of the subtree.
4. Parse the string with ETree into a document and replace the subtree with the root element of the new document.

Alternatively, you could create a new document by wrapping the subtree in `level` wrapper elements, pretty print the whole document and then find the subtree again.

Comment: Thanks, the `.tail` part was what I was looking for. I hardcoded the actual "tails" and it's working fine.